# Is there a CLI command to attach a AWS Layer to my Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-lambda

If I have the Version ARN of a layer, is there a CLI command that I can use to in my Jenkins that will attach the layer to my lambdas function?  I am new to using AWS and Jenkins so I have no idea where to begin with this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is an example of associating a function with a layer in the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-using):

```
$ aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name my-function \
    --layers arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:123456789012:layer:my-layer:3 \
             arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:210987654321:layer:their-layer:2
```